# Cannot resolve symbol Data, Lombok, Component, beans, http, util

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, pom.xml, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am getting cannot resolve symbol for the following in my intelliJ project:

Data, Lombok, Component, beans, http, util

My Class

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("c")
@Data
public class CP {

private String maxTasks;
private String subscribeTo;

}
```

My POM

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you post your entire POM? It looks like there may be something wonky with it.

Comment: Try refreshing the project from the POM

Comment: Did you actually import your code as a Maven project?

Comment: Which version of intellij are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try
File -> Settings -> search for “Annotations” -> Enable annotations -> Select the “Enable annnotations”

Apply and Ok and then restart IntelliJ once.

Answer (score 0):

To make work propertly lombok on intellij it is necessary to use the extension

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok

Comment: Hi how do I use that extention?

Comment: Once you install it then the IDE will provide you the intellisense on the bean. If you use eclipse you should include another extension also to be able to use lombok